# I want to Send Open ID To AWS but it show some cast error which are shown

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin

I want to Send Open ID To AWS

`var mobileClient =  Amplify.Auth.getPlugin("awsCognitoAuthPlugin").escapeHatch as AWSMobileClient?

```
    if (mobileClient != null) {
        mobileClient.federatedSignIn(
            // aws provider URL
            "securetoken.google.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
            idToken,
            object : Callback<UserStateDetails?> {
                override fun onResult(userStateDetails: UserStateDetails?) {
                    Log.e(
                        "AmplifyQuickstar",
                        "sign in success${userStateDetails?.details} ${mobileClient.identityId}"
                    )
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("email", email)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                    Log.e("mmm", "sign-in error", e)
                }
            })
    }
    }`
```

now show bellow error on 1st line "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthService$Companion$fromConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient"